# javascript horizontal center

Tags: javascript, html, center

Im trying to use java script to center a page horizontally.

So far i got this:

```
<body onload="scrollBy((document.body['scrollWidth'] - 0) / 2, 0)">
```

It kinda works, but not very good. I have a large width flash component
that I need centered when the page loads and also after any click on the internal buttons.

I was thinking of making a call from flash to a javascript that would scroll the page to an HTML anchor.

Something along the lines of:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function pageMid() {
 window.location.href="#mid"
 }
 </script>
```

But the anchors don't align to middle.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageMid() {
scrollTo(1000, 0);
}
</script>

 <body onload="pageMid();">
```

Now I just cant figure it out on how to call this from flash catalyst...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to center the element vertically, not horizontally. If you know the size of the element you're trying to center, use CSS:

```
<style>
#myThing {
   height: 300px;
   width: 400px;
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:-150px;
   margin-left:-200px;
}
</style>

<div id="myThing"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but im trying to get it to center horizontally :)

Comment: This should do what you want with CSS.  Substitute the rectanglar div of your choice for body:

<style>
body {
   text-align:center;
}
#myThing {
   margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$(function () {
    scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
});
```

Edit:
I got 2 downvotes for this. Maybe because I did not specify that this solution requires jQuery?